# Symfony 3.4 OneToMany SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shopping_list_id' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

ShoppingList contains many Fruits and Fruits are contained in many ShoppingList with extra field quantity.

I've create a Many To Many Entity called ShoppingRow
So ShoppingList has ManyToOne with ShoppingRow and ShoppingRow has ManyToOne with Fruits

In the action newAction of the ShoppingList, I get an issue:
    An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO shopping_row (quantity, shopping_list_id, fruit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [1, null, 11]:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shopping_list_id' cannot be null
```

source code:

## ShoppingList Entity:

```
/**
 * ShoppingList
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shopping_list")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShoppingListRepository")
 */
class ShoppingList
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ShoppingList
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShoppingRow", mappedBy="shoppingList", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $shoppingRows;
```

## ShoppingListType:

```
class ShoppingListType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('shoppingRows', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ShoppingRowType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
        ))
        ;

    }/**
```

## ShoppingRow Entity:

```
/**
 * ShoppingRow
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shopping_row")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShoppingRowRepository")
 */
class ShoppingRow
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var ShoppingList
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShoppingList", inversedBy="shoppingRows")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shopping_list_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
 private $shoppingList;

 /**
  * @var Fruit
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fruit", inversedBy="shoppingRows")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fruit_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
  */
  private $fruit;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
 */
private $quantity;
```

## ShoppingRowType:

```
class ShoppingRowType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('quantity')
        ->add('fruit', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Fruit',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ));
        ;
    }/**
```

## ShoppingListController:

```
/**
 * Creates a new shopping list entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="shopping_list_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
$shoppingList = new ShoppingList();

$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ShoppingListType', $shoppingList);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($shoppingList);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('shopping_list_show', array('id' => $shoppingList->getId()));
}

return $this->render('shopping_list/new.html.twig', array(
    'shoppingList' => $shoppingList,
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the related entities manually.

```
$shoppingRow->setShoppingList($shoppingList)
```

So for example, if you are adding $shoppingRow to an existing $shoppingList, say, from a form, you need to grab that list and add shoppingList to shopping row. There are many ways you can figure out which list it is, that's your business model - whether you are on the list and you can access it through param converter by passing it's ID in the URI, or by passing it through form's say ChoiceType::class where you've queried your DB for existing lists. This is where we can do little to help you, you need to figure this out on your own.

Now, when you figure out how to get to the list you want, you can either put your code inside a controller or take an approach of doing this in some sort of service that handles your ShoppingLists.

Comment: where to do this ?

Comment: Wherever you have access to both entities, most likely controller. If it's an existing list, you need to get it with EntityManager, if not, you need to instantiate and persist a new one. I will have time later today to explain it a bit further.